# Creating a table

Tags: php, mysql

Probably a simple overlook, but I cannot seem to create a table with my PHP script. My first question is that I want to add a table to an existing DB. How do I tell the server which DB to create the table in? The code to create a table is pretty simple, but here it is ..

> CREATE TABLE Countr(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,Page VARCHAR(50),
>   Month INT, Always INT);

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you connect to the database? You usually tell the system which database to connect to in your connection string. Oh - and I'm guessing your table name is a typo...!

Comment: @HelgiHrafnGunnarsson I would imagine because it's a trivial question: When you connect to make `SELECT` queries, you tell the server which DB you want by using `mysql_select_db()` (or whatever function to that effect is used in the chosen library).

Comment: use mysql_connect(host,user,pass)

Comment: @ArunKillu - did you even read any of the comments before commenting? That function doesn't *select* the database, it connects to the database *daemon*.

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP server you should be connecting to your database. Your code might be like this:

```
mysqli_connect("sqlserver.mysite.com", "username", "password") or die("SQL Error: Cant connect to database.");
```

Then you should do:

```
mysqli_select_db("database_name") or die("SQL Error: Cant select database");
```

to select the database before performing any other sql statements. Such as creating tables.

Comment: sorry, i was 13 minutes late!

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

```
USE my_db1;
CREATE TABLE ...
USE my_db2;
CREATE TABLE ...
```

Comment: if he need to connect to the database to make the operation, why set the database again?

Comment: I'm only showing how to change the current database using mysql statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_select_db('database_name', $link);
CREATE TABLE Countr(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,Page VARCHAR(50), Month INT, Always INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to create table in any database.

```
CREATE TABLE db_name.Countr(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,Page VARCHAR(50), Month INT, Always INT);
```

Note: Current database user has create table privileges in the other database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE wp_shifts (
    user_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transact_id int(64),
    hours decimal(10,2), 
    date varchar(64),
    time1 varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)";
$results = $wpdb->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Table
The CREATE TABLE statement is used to create a table in MySQL.

We must add the CREATE TABLE statement to the mysqli_query() function to execute the command.

The following example creates a table named "Persons", with three columns: "FirstName", "LastName" and "Age":

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Create table
$sql="CREATE TABLE Persons(FirstName CHAR(30),LastName CHAR(30),Age INT)";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Table persons created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
?>
```